# Are bash builtins preferable to UNIX tools for performance reasons?

Tags: bash, performance

I'm trying to understand when it's appropriate to use "unix tools" vs BASH capabilities.  Let's say for example I want to divide a string in two parts based on some delimiter.  Does using "cut" invoke some kind of process/thread/external processing that is generally slower than using some other "built-in BASH utility" to divide a string in two, whatever that might be?

Comment: Use the `time` function to measure them?

Comment: I'd like the general conceptual understanding

Comment: More likely than not, the builtins will not give you all the functionality you need. You should take a look at: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Comment: Thanks @ryanpcmcquen

Comment: I really do think there's a fact-based question in here, even if it was originally worded in a way that made it look like a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling external tools incurs a substantial performance penalty.

Let's test this ourselves, comparing 10,000 iterations of `cut` against 10,000 iterations of a parameter expansion:

```
# for me, this is ~50s wall-clock
time for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do
  in_str='hello:world'
  cut -d: -f2 <<<"$in_str" # External tool!
done >/dev/null
```

...vs...

```
# for me, this is ~0.2s wall-clock
time for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do
  in_str='hello:world'
  printf '%s\n' "${in_str#*:}" # Builtin!
done >/dev/null
```

Copy-and-paste both of these, and see how your results differ. :)

On my system, the built-in version runs in less than a second, whereas the external version takes about 50 seconds to run. Thus, we're right around 8 base-2 orders of magnitude.

---

Now, for a *conceptual* understanding -- one of the key things to understand is that all work involved in the builtin is performed internal to bash, whereas the external tool requires substantial overhead to invoke:

- `fork()` off a second copy of the bash process
- `execve()` to replace that new process with a copy of the desired external executable (which typically requires the OS to invoke its linker and loader to spin up a dynamic binary)
- `wait()` for that process to finish

...and, if you're capturing the output, then a FIFO needs to be created and read from as well. Thus, the very act of starting up an external tool is often much slower than that tool's time spent executing its desired function.

---

That said -- if you were attentive, you may have noticed that this constructed a worst-case scenario for `cut`, processing only one line of input per invocation. Results would be very different for this:

```
# for me, this is ~0.12s wall-clock
time for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do
  printf '%s\n' 'hello:world'
done | cut -d: -f2 >/dev/null
```

...wherein only one invocation of `cut` is used for the entire stream, spreading that startup time across a very large number of lines of input.

When the job involves processing bulk input, rather than one line at a time, external tools *can* be more efficient when used correctly.

Comment: Thanks Charles.   Using my cygwin the speed diff is 1300:1.

Comment: @Ray, *nod* -- `fork()` is a slower / more expensive call on Windows.

Comment: Guess I better study those bash builtins! :-)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 is a good place to start.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks too for your thorough answer explaining where the time is spent, conceptually.

Comment: Interesting on the one invocation of cut on bulk I/O

Comment: Yup. BTW, bash is a rather exceptionally slow shell -- you'd get much better numbers from shell-native builtins if you were using, say, ksh93.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html), *builtins execute faster than external commands, which usually require forking off a separate process*, so if you cared deeply about performance you should do things with built-ins when you can, although we're talking about an improvement on the order of the time to fork a process.

This will usually only matters when you're running the same command multiple times in a tight loop, rather than processing an entire input with a single command.

One additional note is that if you have accidentally fork-bombed your machine, you will no longer be able to run new processes but you will be able to run built-in's like `kill` to try to recover.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: linking the ABS. (Not that it's wrong on this particular point, but because it has a reputation for showcasing bad practices unrelated to whatever point it's trying to make... and thus being a dangerous piece of documentation for anyone who doesn't already know the language well enough to separate the wheat from the chaff).

Comment: ...incidentally, the page you linked to has several such bad practices -- places where its sample code doesn't use enough quoting to be robust against unusual filenames; places where it doesn't follow POSIX variable naming conventions; places where it uses command substitution syntax that isn't formally deprecated but also has a preferred replacement... and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Speed is not bash's selling point, or unix tools either. Builtins are faster. That said, bash should be used like a first-aid kit: use it when you need something now and quick. If your script starts getting more complicated and you start caring more about speed, you should probably go to something more powerful, like Python.

Comment: To an extent I agree, but then, if speed is your goal Python isn't exactly the best choice either. I'd suggest Golang for folks who want a language well-suited to systems-level utility programming with a focus on performant execution.

Comment: That said, the difference between bash builtins and external tools is literally orders-of-magnitude, meaning that well-written bash is useful in situations where crappy (ie. doing-everything-with-externals) bash is too slow. The general rule of "if you care about speed whatsoever, don't use bash at all" is one I disagree with: Well-written bash is often fast enough in places where poorly-written bash is not.

Comment: I agree, @CharlesDuffy golang is better for speed, and not much more complicated than python :)

Comment: ...and then faster shells, such as ksh (David Korn ksh, not the almost-uniformly-awful clones), are downright speedy: ksh93 is often on par with awk, and *faster* than Python for bulk text processing.

Comment: (I might also argue that for some implementations of some UNIX tools speed _is_ a selling point. GNU sort, for instance, puts a lot of work into performance -- particularly on datasets too large to hold in memory at once; see in particular the parallelism support in modern releases; the divide-and-conquer support for large buffers, by contrast, has been there for ages).